# Register new T_OPEN_TAG and T_CLOSE_TAG through a C extension?

Tags: php, php-extension, php-internals

I'm working on a PHP C extension that needs to register new *T_OPEN_TAG* `<?` and *T_CLOSE_TAG* `?>` tags. I don't want to overwrite *T_OPEN_TAG* and *T_CLOSE_TAG*, just register new tokens.

Is it possible for a PHP C extension to register new PHP tags? Ex:

```
<: 1+1 :>
```

PS: the example above is just an example ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to register new tokens. The only way to do it would be to copy the PHP lexer in its entirety, add your modifications, and then hook your custom lexer into `zend_compile_file` and `zend_compile_string`. You don't want to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yep, definitely I don't want to do that. Would be nice to be able to extend the language syntax through extensions, BTW.